# How to construct a mesh from a set of vertices

Tags: c++, glut, mesh, vertices

I am making an OBJ importer and I happen to be stuck on how to construct the mesh from a set of given vertices.  Consider a cube with these vertices (OBJ format, faces are triangles:

```
v -2.767533 -0.000000 2.927381

v 3.017295 -0.000000 2.927381

v -2.767533 6.311718 2.927381

v 3.017295 6.311718 2.927381

v -2.767533 6.311718 -2.845727

v 3.017295 6.311718 -2.845727

v -2.767533 -0.000000 -2.845727

v 3.017295 -0.000000 -2.845727
```

I know how to construct meshes using GLUT (to make my calls to GlBegin(GL_TRIANGLES), glVertex3f(x, y, z), glEnd(), etc.)  Its just that I don't know how to combine the vertices to recreate the object.  I thought it was to go v1, v2, v3, then v2, v3, v4, etc. until I have made enough triangles (and something like v7, v8, v1 (because it goes back to the begining)) counts.  So 8 vertices is 12 triangles for the cube, and for, say, a sphere with 108 triangles and 56 vertices is (56 vertices * 2) - 4.  For a cube, I make the 12 triangles, its ok but for a sphere, I make the 108 triangles with 56 vertices, it does not work.  So how do I combine the vertices in my glVertex calls to make it work for any mesh?  Thank you!

Comment: there are libraries that will do this for you http://assimp.sourceforge.net/ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a bunch of "face" lines in the file (lines beginning with the letter "f") that tell you how to combine the vertices into an object.  For example,

```
f 1 2 3
```

would mean a triangle composed of the first three vertices in the file.  You might also see something like

```
f 1/1 2/2 3/3
```

which is a triangle that also includes texture coordinates,

```
f 1//1 2//2 3//3
```

which includes vertex normal vectors, or

```
f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3
```

which is one that includes both.

Wikipedia has an article that includes an overview of the format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file

Comment: Ok that solves it.  What I was doing was working on the parts of the file one part at a time, like I would start with the vertices, then deal with the texture coordinates.  The way wikipedia explained it was not clear to me that I needed to use the vertices and face definitions together.